# child process spawn returning NaN

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to understand child process module in *node.js*, I created a parent file which has code:

```
var spawn=require("child_process").spawn;
var child=spawn("node",['plus_one.js']);
setInterval(function(){
    //var number=Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
    var number=10;
    child.stdin.write(number + "\n");
    child.stdout.once("data",function(data){
        console.log("Child replied  to "+number + " with " + data);
    })
},1000);
child.stderr.on("data",function(data){
    //process.stdout.write(data);
    console.log("error"+data)
})
```

The child file looks like this:

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.on("data",function(data){
var number;
try{
    number = parseInt(data.toString(), 10);

    number+=1;
    process.stdout.write(number+"\n");
}
catch(err){
    process.stderr.write(err.message+"lol");
}
})
```

If I execute just the child file it works fine , but when i execute the main file it always return `NaN`; why is that?

Also as im trying to understand it, I quite do not understand the difference between `child_process.spawn` and `.exec`,  `spawn` return *stream* so it has stdin/stdout while `exec` returns *buffer*, does it mean that `.exec` cannot communicate with child file (and vice versa) other than passing variable with options/env object in it?

Comment: Do you realize that you're adding a new `child.stdout.on()` handler in every timer interval and they will ALL be active?

Comment: oh right sorry , it should be .once() and was checking with .on() ,  forgot to put it back , thanks for pointing out !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a few tweaks to your code, it is now working for me:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var child = spawn("node", ['plus_one.js']);
var number = 10;

setInterval(function () {
    child.stdin.write(number++ + "\n");
    child.stdout.once("data", function (data) {
        console.log("Child replied  to " + number + " with " + data);
    });
}, 1000);

child.stderr.on("data", function (data) {
    //process.stdout.write(data);
    console.log("error" + data)
});
```

Changes:

1. Used proper bracing on the `setInterval()` function.
2. Used `.once()` in the appropriate place so event handlers don't pile up.
3. Moved the `number` variable outside of the `setInterval()` scope so that it can retain its value from one call to the next.